# Google Earth Engine Error: "Layer error: No valid training data were found"

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, land-cover

I make a classification of landcover for 13 years from 2010 to 2022, but in 2022 I get "Layer error: No valid training data were found"

```
//Pemunculan SHP
var shp = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/paulusmg/assets/Kota_Sibolga")
Map.addLayer(shp, {}, 'sibolga')

//Bebas Awan
var maskL8 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('BQA');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var composite = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
        .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31')
         .map(maskL8)
          .median()
          .clip(table);

//visualisasi citra satelit true color dan false color
var RGBTrue = composite.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);
var RGBparam = { min: 0, max: 0.3,};
Map.addLayer(RGBTrue, RGBparam, 'truecolor');

var RGBFalse = composite.select(['B6','B5','B3']);
var RGBparam = { min: 0, max: 0.3,};
Map.addLayer(RGBFalse, RGBparam, 'falsecolor');

//Tahap Klasifikasi
var aoi = Terbangun.merge(Non_Terbangun).merge(Badan_Air);

var bands = ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'];

var training = composite.select(bands).sampleRegions({
collection: aoi,
properties: ['lc'],
scale: 30
});

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
features: training,
classProperty: 'lc',
inputProperties: bands
});

var classified2022 = composite.select(bands).classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer(classified2022,
{min: 0, max: 2, palette:['orange','green','blue']},
'Tuplah2022');
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a working example please? Terbangun, Non_Terbangun, Badan_Air are not defined in the script, so we cannot test the script.